# ¿Las lineas en el código vacias hacen que este sea más difícil de leer o la página web se cargue mas lento?

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5

En mi código siempre dejo una linea vacia entre cada linea de código para que sea más comodo para el ojo, y me preguntaba si eso afecta en algun modo a la velocidad de su lectura en el navegador o si es que da lo mismo. Me ayudaría mucho que me saquen esa duda

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de que esto no sea un problema per sé, quiero explicarte al respecto.

En palabras cortas si, cada espacio o salto de línea agrega un minúsculo peso adicional al tamaño de lo que estés escribiendo, por ejemplo HTML o CSS.

Sin embargo si esto te preocupa, puedes siempre utilizar una herramienta que te permita minificar los archivos, en la mayoría de los casos te estarás ahorrando unos cuántos kilobytes.

Dicho esto, *no* es necesario que hagas código en una sola línea para evitar el peso.